# Dense and compeltely regular space

Tags: general-topology

Let    $T $ be a topologica space and $X $  a completely regular dense subspace of $T $. Why is $T $ compeletly regular?

Comment: Why do you think this is true? Missing no assumptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false as stated : let $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ be a completey regular space and define $T  =X \cup \{p\}$, where $p \notin X$. Then define a topology on $T$ as $\mathcal{T}_X \cup \{T\}$. The resulting space is not even Hausdorff, but has $X$ as a dense subspace.

Comment: Thanks for your nice response.

Comment: @Deroty Well, it's not the result you hoped for? There is a simple result that being completely regular is hereditary. So a space $X$ can only be embedded in a completely regular space $Y$ (densely or not) if $X$ was completely regular to start with.